# clickhouse_driver.errors.ServerException: Code: 62.DB::Exception: Syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, intervals, clickhouse

I have an error in function.

`self.client` is click house driver --- `from clickhouse_driver import Client`

I called function with keys = "4"

```
def multi_get(self, keys: str) -> dict:
        if not self.initialized:
            self.make_table()
        keys_joined = "'" + "', '".join(keys) + "'"
        print(f"PPPP_1 {keys_joined}") # 4
        found = self.client.execute(
            f'SELECT max(arrivalTime), key, argMax(data, arrivalTime)'
            f' FROM {self.database}.cache'
            f' WHERE key in ({keys_joined})'
            f' and arrivalTime > now() - INTERVAL {self.expiration_interval}'
            ' GROUP BY key'
        )
```

And received error. **How can I fix the error?**

> File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/client.py", line 118, in receive_packet
> raise packet.exception
> clickhouse_driver.errors.ServerException: Code: 62.
> DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 137 ('GROUP'): GROUP BY key. Expected one of: HOUR, DD, SQL_TSI_QUARTER, S, SQL_TSI_YEAR, YEAR, LIKE,

Answer (score 0):

The error message is trying to tell you.

Here:

```
and arrivalTime > now() - INTERVAL {self.expiration_interval}
```

This generates invalid SQL. The `INTERVAL` requires a unit, like `INTERVAL 1 HOUR`, or else. The list of supported types can be found [in the documentation](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/special-data-types/interval/):

> ```
> SECOND
> MINUTE
> HOUR
> DAY
> WEEK
> MONTH
> QUARTER
> YEAR
> ```

Maybe you want:

```
and arrivalTime > now() - INTERVAL {self.expiration_interval} HOUR
```